# PayPal IPN email not working

Tags: php, email, paypal, paypal-ipn

When I send the IPN, it says it was sent successfully. However, I never receive an email at my test email. What is wrong with my code to cause it to not send? Also, when I am ready for it to be open to the public, how would I change the ToEmail from xxx@myemail.com to the email of the individual that purchased my item? I'm not very knowledgeable with PHP, this is my first time attempting an IPN but I'm helping a nonprofit business with their website and I'm having a bit of trouble getting this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

```
<?php
//Build the data to post back to Paypal
$postback = 'cmd=_notify-validate'; 

// go through each of the posted vars and add them to the postback variable
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$postback .= "&$key=$value";
}

// build the header string to post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($postback) . "\r\n\r\n";

// Send to paypal or the sandbox depending on whether you're live or developing
//comment out one of the following lines
//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);//open the connection
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
// or use port 443 for an SSL connection
//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) 
{
    // HTTP ERROR Failed to connect
    //error handling
}
else // if we've connected OK
{
    fputs ($fp, $header . $postback);//post the data back
    while (!feof($fp)) 
    {
        $response = fgets ($fp, 1024);

        if (strcmp ($response, "VERIFIED") == 0) //It's verified
        {
$ToEmail = 'xxx@myemail.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Subject Here'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST['receiver_email']."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST['receiver_email']."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST['first_name'].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "
I will write my message here."; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "
Thank you,
MY COMPANY NAME"; 
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader);
        }
        else if (strcmp ($response, "INVALID") == 0) 
        { 
            //the Paypal response is INVALID, not VERIFIED
            // This implies something is wrong
        }
    } //end of while
    fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the script from HTTP/1.0 to HTTP/1.1
and add both Host: and Connection: entries.

```
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($postback) . "\r\n\r\n";
```

Should be

```
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($postback) . "\r\n\r\n";
```